# jersey restful com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: java, angularjs, eclipse, rest, maven

Note:The answers in the related threads for the same question didn't work for me.

I am designing a web application with angularJS as my frontend and java as my backend.I am communicating with my java classes using a RESTful service. I am using Eclipse kepler as my IDE, Maven 2.0.2 as my build manager and jersey 1.17.1 in java 6. Also I am using Websphere 7 for deploying the resource.
This is my maven folder structure:
[image]

A snippet from my pom.xml is as follows:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also my web.xml reads as follows:

```
<web-app>
<display-name>KB</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
</servlet-class>

<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>rest</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>

<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- .. -->

</web-app>
```

Following is my code from the controller in angular js used for calling the service:

```
 $scope.triggerDataRetrival=function(docName){
    alert("inside func");
    var url = "rest/retrieve/doc?name="+docName;
    $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
        $scope.docInfo = response;
     });

     }
```

And finally my service class goes as follows:

```
package rest;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/retrieve")
public class retrieve {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/doc")
//@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getResponse(@QueryParam("name") String doctype){
    System.out.println("doctype:"+doctype);
    return "success";
}
}
```

I have tried a lot of things suggested on multiple threads for this question But nothing seems to work. The error that is shown in the console is `com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.`. Any help will be really great.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you try to remove the following completely from your web.xml?

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>rest</param-value>
</init-param>
```